# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 124

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-2014-express

Trying to access a SQL Server 2014 database with Visual Studio 2017; on each run, it shows this error

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 124

Read some questions already on stack overflow but they are of other context. Like asp.net or azure database etc

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EMPLOYES" 
             connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-0ROOGH3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMPLOYES;Integrated Security = true;System.Dat.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMPLOYES"].ConnectionString;

    // here I get the exception
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString); 

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddNewEmployee", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8).Value = EmpIDTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastNmae", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = LastNameTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = EmailTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telephone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TelephoneTextBox.Text;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Employee is added successfully!");
}
```

I expected to insert records but it generates some exception

Comment: I would highly doubt a connection string could handle new lines and carriage returns in parameters, is this how it truly look in your app.config?

Comment: (plus `System.Dat.SqlClient` looks very suspicious)

Comment: @Alexei yes i got that and now it's working good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string looks completely garbled, try something like

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>

       <add name="EMPLOYES" 
            connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-0ROOGH3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMPLOYES;Integrated Security = true;" 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    </connectionStrings>
</connectionStrings>
```

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)
- [SqlClient Connection Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax#sqlclient-connection-strings)